# Opening/Writing to a file from a Kprobe handler

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kprobe

I am writing a Linux kernel module using `Kprobes` to trace specific system calls, and I need to write to a file from within a `KProbe` handler (specifically, a `Kretprobe`). I know this is generally not advised, but I need to write the output to a very specific location, so I can't use any standard logging mechanisms.

I can open/write fine from the `init()` function in the module, but when I try to do so from within a probe handler, the kernel crashes.

Answer (score 3):

From Documentation/kprobes.txt:

> Probe handlers are run with preemption disabled.  Depending on the
>   architecture and optimization state, handlers may also run with
>   interrupts disabled (e.g., kretprobe handlers and optimized kprobe
>   handlers run without interrupt disabled on x86/x86-64).  In any case,
>   your handler should not yield the CPU (e.g., by attempting to acquire
>   a semaphore).

In other words, **you cannot sleep inside probe handler**. Because read/write operations with file normally use disk I/O, you cannot use these operations inside the handler.

> I need to write the output to a very specific location, so I can't use any standard logging mechanisms.

You can output trace from probe handler, e.g., into the special device file, and run(in parallel) user-space program, which simply reads that file and writes into one at *very specific location*.